# Recycler View in Nested Scroll View lags performance

Tags: java, android, performance, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I have a recycler view inside nested scroll view. When there is too much data in recycler view, the scroll gets lagged. Is there any way to solve this issue other than taking the recycler view out of nested scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`

Comment: I already disabled nested scrolling. I changed from Glide to Picasso, the performance is good now. Thanks!!!